# Is there a generalization of Granville-Langevin conjecture for number fields?

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request, abc-conjecture

According to Wikipedia and other sources the Granville-Langevin conjecture
states:

> If $f$ is a square-free binary form of degree $n > 2$, then for every real $\beta > 2$ there is a constant $C(f,\beta)$ such for all coprime integer $x,y$, 
>   the radical of $f(x,y)$ exceeds $C(f,\beta) \max\{|x|,|y|\}^{n-\beta}$

It is equivalent to the $abc$-conjecture.

> Is it possible to generalize Granville-Langevin conjecture to
>   number fields or the ring of integers of number fields?
>
> Would someone suggest a generalization?

Such generalization exists for $abc$.

A naive approach is just to take norms.

The relation with $abc$ is that $f(x,y)$ might be a part of a
polynomial identity with difference of degrees just $2$.
If GL fails, abc will fail because of the small radical.