# Diophantine equations with infinitely many large solutions

Tags: nt.number-theory, diophantine-equations

Let $F(x,y)$ be a squarefree binary form with integer coefficients,
possibly reducible, $\deg(F) \ge 3$.

I am interested in ways of getting infinitely many integer solutions $(x,y,m), m \ne 0$
to $F(x,y)=m$, maximizing $\max(|x|,|y|)$ relative to $m$.

More formally, suppose $F$ is as above, $f$ is an increasing function, and for infinitely many $x,y,m$, $m \ne 0$ the following hold:

1) $F(x,y)=m$.

2) $\max(|x|,|y|) \ge f(|m|,\deg(F))$ or
$\max(|x|,|y|) \ge f(|m|)$

> How fast can $f$ grow?

Partial result: For $\deg(F)=3$, it is possible to have $f(m)=C m$ for $C$ an arbitrary large constant depending on $F$. This may be best possible for $F$ of degree $3$.

---

**Added later** The construction with $f(|m|)= C m$
as suggested in comments:

For $C \sim \varphi^{k+1}$, we can take $f(|m|)= C m$ and
$$G(x,y) = (F_{k+1} x - F_k y) (x^2 + x y - y^2)$$
where $F_k$ is the $k^{th}$ Fibonacci number.

Then we can take $x=F_n$, $y=F_{n+1}$, $m=(-1)^{n+1} F_{n-k}$.

We have the identities

$$ F_{k+1} F_n - F_k F_{n+1} \ = \ F_{k+1} x - F_k y \ = \ F_{n-k} $$
$$ F_n^2 + F_n F_{n+1} - F_{n+1}^2 \ = \ x^2 + xy - y^2 \ = \ (-1)^{n+1}.$$

which yield $G(x,y) = m$.

This construction seems to give an unbounded number
$G(x_i,y_i)$
of unbounded quality for the [Granville-Langevin conjecture](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/149631/is-there-a-generalization-of-granville-langevin-conjecture-for-number-fields), which is equivalent to $abc$ without 
using the radical at all.

This is a lower bound for $f(|m|)$ and experimentally
there are much better solutions with the same $G$,
though I don't know if they are infinite (probably not).

Multiplying $G$ by similar linear factors, I believe
one can get $f(|m|)=C |m|^{\frac{1}{(\deg(G)-2)}}$.

Comment: In 1), do you mean "There are infinitely many $m$ such that $F(x,y)=m$ has integer solutions"? In 2), do you intend to take the maximum over all solutions, not just over a pair which constitutes one solution?

Comment: @GNiklasch yes, exactly. As I wrote $x,y,m$ are integers.

Comment: My point was to clarify what you're quantifying over and how. "Thue equation" connotes that one nonzero value of $m$ is picked and kept fixed. So you're really looking at infinitely many Thue equations built around the same binary homogeneous form, right?

Comment: @GNiklasch yes, $F$ is fixed and $m$ varies, so these indeed are infinitely many Thue equations.In addition I allow reducible $F$.

Comment: @GNiklasch Re: "In 2)" infinitely many solutions (x,y,m) must satisfy 2) for fixed $F,f$.

Comment: Is it easy, for degree 3, to find an $F$ such that $f(m)=Cm$ for some (sizable) constant $C$?

Comment: @GerryMyerson I can give the construction in the question for unbounded $C$ if you'd like? It is not rocket science, but it was not _very_ easy for me.

Comment: Sure, let's see it.

Comment: @GerryMyerson edited the question with unbounded C.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If the degree of the form is $d$, I think you get solutions with $f(|m|) > cm^{1/(d-2)}$ by applying Dirichlet's theorem in diophantine approximation to a root of $F(x,1)=0$. And you cannot do better than $cm^{1/(d-2)+\epsilon}$ by Thue-Siegel-Roth.

Comment: Thank you. Would you please explain in more detail why one can't do better?

Comment: $F(x,y)=m$ is the same as $F(x/y,1)=m/y^d$ and, since $F$ is squarefree, $F(x/y,1)$ is, up to a constant, close to $(x/y - \alpha)$ for some root $\alpha$ of $F(x,1)=0$. Now apply Thue-Siegel-Roth.

Comment: Thank you. For the construction do you mean _real_ root? Little can be done about $F(x,y)=x^4+y^4$.

Comment: You are correct, the construction only applies if there is a real, irrational, root.